# LeetCode: Minimum Number of Days to Eat N Oranges

Tags: java, recursion

I ran into this problem today at the Leetcode contest and I have written a code for that problem but it doesn't work, Can anyone tell me what conditions am I missing?

Link for the question:[Minimum Number of Days to Eat N Oranges](https://leetcode.com/contest/weekly-contest-202/problems/minimum-number-of-days-to-eat-n-oranges/)

**Question:-**

There are n oranges in the kitchen and you decided to eat some of these oranges every day as follows:

- Eat one orange.
- If the number of remaining oranges (n) is divisible by 2 then you can eat  n/2 oranges.
- If the number of remaining oranges (n) is divisible by 3 then you can eat  2*(n/3) oranges. You can only choose one of the actions per day.

Return the minimum number of days to eat n oranges.

**My solution:**

```
class Solution {
static int Norange(int n, int days){
    
    //no more oranges left
    if(n <= 0)
        return days;
    
    //increment days
    ++days;
    
    //divisible by 2
    if(n % 2 == 0)
        return Math.min(Norange(n - 1 , days), Norange(n/2, days));
    
    //not divisible by 2 and 3
    else if( n % 2 != 0 && n % 3 != 0)
        return Norange(n - 1, days);
    
    //divisible by 3
    return Math.min(Norange(n - 1, days), Norange( n - 2*(n/3), days ));
}

public int minDays(int n) {
    
    return Norange(n, 0);
    
}
```

}

***It is not passing the test case for input: 182***

Comment: Is a recursive solution required?  And posting links is hot helpful (especially so when you need an account to see the information).  Please ensure you post the `exact` wording and requirements of the challenge.  And be cautious as this post could be removed due to copyright infringement.  I have seen it done before by code challenge sites.

Comment: Java naming conventions have methods and variables start with a lower case letter (nOrange), while classes start with an upper case letter.

Comment: I want to add to the question that the n varies from 1 to 2*10^9. The memoization and tabulation algorithms are giving TLE for values like 3681069. Could anyone please give algorithm regarding that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @WJS remarked in their now-deleted answer, you do not accommodate the case where `n` is divisible by both 2 and 3.  To your credit, however, you seem to recognize that a greedy algorithm does not work -- eating just one orange on a given day is sometimes the right move even when there are more than two oranges available.  You could accommodate the multiple-of-six issue with a relatively small adjustment to your code:

```
static int Norange(int n, int days){
    
    //no more oranges left
    if(n <= 0)
        return days;
    
    //increment days
    ++days;

    int min = Norange(n - 1 , days);
    
    //divisible by 2
    if(n % 2 == 0)
        min = Math.min(min, Norange(n/2, days));
    
    //divisible by 3
    if(n % 3 == 0)
        min = Math.min(min, Norange( n - 2*(n/3), days ));

    return min;
}
```

Do note, however, that although algorithmically correct, this formulation has terrible performance characteristics as `n` increases, arising from recomputing the same partial results over and over and over.  To make it work for moderately large inputs, you will need to employ memoization to avoid that.

For example, `Norange()` could accept an `int` array of length (at least) `n + 1` as an additional argument.  The top-level caller would be expected to instantiate that array (default initialization to all-zeroes is fine).  Then each `Norange()` call would set element `n` of that array to its final result, and, moreover, would use the partial results recorded there to avoid recursing whenever possible.  Details are left as an exercise.

Comment: Yeah.  I deleted my answer because my assumptions were naive.  Interesting problem though.  Back to the drawing board.

Comment: This solution is working just fine, it doesn't give wrong answer for any input but as you mentioned it does give time limit exceed error for large inputs like 673.

Comment: I was curious about how many recursive calls it would take so I put in a static counter at the beginning of the method.  For `673` it took `1,701,575,892` calls.  And I don't consider 673 large considering possible values of `n` from subsequent clarifying comments.

Answer (score 1):

It is easier to write bottom up dp solution or same way recursive solution.
But it won't work for larger number.
in that question n could be up to 2x10^9. calculating all the sates in dp would give you TLE.
so, we have to do some kind of pruning. when number is large, it doesn't make sense to eat one orange a day. we can always try to reduce the number to nearest number divisible by 2 or 3; then can consume n/2 or 2*n/3 oranges and take the path which gives minimum number of days.

Here is code for dp bottom up

```
 public int minDaysBottomUp(int n) {
    if(n <2)return 1;
    int[] dp = new int[n+1];
    dp[1] =1;
    dp[2] = 2;

    for(int i =3; i <=n; i++){
        dp[i] =Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    }
    for(int i=3; i <=n; i++){
        
        if(i%3 ==0 && i%2 ==0 ){
            int a = i-2*(i/3);
            int b = i-(i/2);
            dp[i] =1+ Math.min(dp[i-1], Math.min(dp[a], dp[b]));
        }
        else if(i%3==0){
            int a = i-2*(i/3);
         //   System.out.println(" 3 "+ rem);
            dp[i] = 1+ Math.min(dp[i-1], dp[a]);         
            
        }else if ( i %2==0){
            int b = i-(i/2);
       
            dp[i]= 1+Math.min(dp[i-1], dp[b]);
        }
        dp[i] = Math.min(dp[i], 1+dp[i-1]);
        

    }
    return dp[n];

}
```

Here is recursive dp with memoization which works for all:

```
  Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
public int minDaysOptimized(int n){
    if(n <=1) return n;
    if(map.containsKey(n))return map.get(n);
    
     int ans = 1 + Math.min(n%2 + minDays(n/2), n%3+ minDays(n/3));
     map.put(n, ans);
     return ans;
        
    
}
```

Comment: Where is `minDays`?

Comment: minimum number of days to eat orange same  Norange() metthod @WJS

Comment: `Norange` takes two arguments.  What's the second one in your optimized method?

Answer (score -1):

I think this will be much cleaner!

```
public class OrangeInDays {
    
    static int days;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        System.out.println(minDays());
        
    }
    
    
    private static int minDays() {
        countDays(293);
        return days;
    }


    public static void countDays(int orng) {
        
        if(orng !=0 ) {
            if(orng%3 == 0) {
                
                orng -= 2*(orng/3);
                
            }
            else if(orng%2 ==0 && orng%3 != 1) {
                
                orng -= orng/2; 
            }else if(orng%2 ==0 && ((orng-1)/3)%2!=0 && ((orng-1)/3)%3!=0) {
                orng -= orng/2;
            }
            else {
                orng--;
            }

            countDays(orng);
            days++;
        }
        
    }

}
```

Comment: I believe the author wanted to do a recursive solution.

Comment: How did you know that?

Comment: Well, the OP's attempt is a recursive solution, and the OP included a `recursion` tag in the question.

Comment: Although now it's recursive, there's also the problem that this gives the wrong answer for some inputs.  The exercise is not amenable to a greedy solution: sometimes the optimal move is to eat only one orange even though there are more than two left.  Consider 10 as the input, for example.  This approach yields five days (10 -> 5 -> 4 -> 2 -> 1 -> 0), but the optimal solution takes only four days (10 -> 9 -> 3 -> 1 -> 0).

Comment: Also, code-only answers tend not to be well regarded around here.  We love code, but we prefer to also see some prose to explain the factors involved and describe how the code presented addresses those.

Comment: I think answer of John Bollinger is not work correctly for input value 293.